# A mutlipage site with SASS using Webpack as build tool

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

I am building a multi page site that uses SASS along with the commons like HTML, CSS JS and webpack. Which works just fine locally when I run npm start, which triggers my webpack.dev.js please refer to the screenshot npm start.png.

Similarly when I run the npm run build command, in my project I would like my ./sass/main.scss file to get compiled and bundled into the dist folder, which will then serve and style all the html pages that are generated in the ./dist folder. Instead when I run the npm run build command it does create the ./dist folder, the html files and css files but the style is not injected into the html.

So to summarise I don't get any specific error as such but instead I don't get a desired outcome after running my webpack.prod.js as mentioned above.

So the problem is in the plugins and the module section of the webpack.prod.js, that is the way I have setup to spit out the css, js and the html pages

The repo has all the files including the ./dist folder and screenshots of the commands npm start and npm run build and the file structure as well

My github repo is https://github.com/kekir/WP-experiment
hope that helps
thanks again